# when does the complex square root exists?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open connected subset not containing the origin. Define $f(z):\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=z^2$. What conditions on $\Omega$ do we need so there exists a continuous function $h(z):\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(h(z))=z$? Is it necessary and sufficient that $\Omega$ does not contain a closed curve going around the origin?

Comment: Did you mean "_not_ containing the origin"? If so then the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: yes, thanks for pointing that out. How do I see that the answer is yes?

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hypothesis,  more formally stated, is that every closed curve in $\Omega$ has winding number $0$ about the origin. This says precisely that $$\int_\gamma\frac{dz}z=0$$for every smooth closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$.

*That* in turn says there exists a branch of the logarithm. Fix $a\in\Omega$ and "define" $L(z)$ for $z\in\Omega$ by saying that $L(z)=\int_\gamma\frac{dw}w$, where $\gamma$ is a path from $a$ to $z$. The above shows that $L(z)$ is independent of which path we chose, and it follows that $L$ is holomorphic in  $\Omega$ with $L'(z)=1/z$. It follows from *that* that there exists $c$ so $$e^{L(z)+c}=z.$$ (Proof: Show $\left(ze^{-L(z)}\right)'=0$.)

Let $h(z)=e^{(L(z)+c)/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

It can't happen.  An open set containing $0$ contains a circle centred at $0$.

Comment: sorry, I meant not containing the origin.